# Convert String to date, Throws ParseException

Tags: java, android, datetime

I want to convert the string `11-7-2013 10:51:10` to a `Date object`.

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"); 
try {
    String date = "11-7-2013 10:51:10"
    return formatter.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have the following code, But I'm getting a `ParseException`.

Comment: your format has **slashes**, your string **dashes**...

Comment: ..therefore the program **crashes**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"); 
try {
    String date = "11-7-2013 10:51:10"
    return formatter.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In SimpleDateFormat the string passed to constructor is the same representation of date format that date is going to parse by this formatter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "-" instead of "/" in your date format as your date string contains "-" ,

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"); 
try {
    String date = "11-7-2013 10:51:10"
    return formatter.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

instanse of

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways here

```
"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" with String Date ="11/7/2013 10:51:10";
```

or

```
 "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" with String Date="11-7-2013 10:51:10";
```

Answer (score -1):

please refer the below format

tring string = "January 2, 2010";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);